# Clonezilla is not able to clone a RAID 1 disk

Tags: linux, raid1, clonezilla

I have a HP Server DL320 G5. There are two SATA hard disks configured as RAID 1 through HP embedded RAID controller. Server OS is running GNU/Linux (Fedora)

Server booted up with clonezilla live CD. The image will be stored on a NAS connected through NFS.
Clonezilla could mount the NFS share and could see the two hard disks `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`.

I selected `/dev/sda` for disk cloning. However I could not see the cloning progress and got straight into a prompt for reboot, poweroff, command line

I tried to select `/dev/sdb` but the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Clonezilla lacks automatic support for this feature:

"Software RAID/fake RAID/firmware RAID is not supported by default. It can be done manually only."

See ["Limitations"](http://clonezilla.org/) on the Clonezilla web page.